# upgraded to 14.04 LTS, VLC is not working

Tags: 14.04, vlc, qt

recently upgraded to ubuntu 14.04 lts from ubuntu 12.04 lts.

now vlc doesn't start.

in terminal following output occurred -

```
$ vlc
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4+git20141006+r54582+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1)
[0x8c1c910] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x8ca4a00] skins2 interface error: no suitable dialogs provider found (hint: compile the qt4 plugin, and make sure it is loaded properly)
[0x8ca4a00] skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs provider
[0x8ca4a00] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
>
```

how to fix it?

**output for commands -**

```
$ vlc -I skins2
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4+git20141006+r54582+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1)
[0x9ba39c0] skins2 interface error: no suitable dialogs provider found (hint: compile the qt4 plugin, and make sure it is loaded properly)
[0x9ba39c0] skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs provider
[0x9ba39c0] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x9b1b910] main libvlc error: interface "default" initialization failed
```

and

```
$ vlc -I qt4
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4+git20141006+r54582+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1)
[0x8bd37e0] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x8b4b910] main libvlc error: interface "default" initialization failed
```

and

```
$ vlc --ignore-config
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4+git20141006+r54582+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1)
[0x9822910] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x98ab930] skins2 interface error: no suitable dialogs provider found (hint: compile the qt4 plugin, and make sure it is loaded properly)
[0x98ab930] skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs provider
[0x98ab930] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
>
```

and

```
$ vlc --reset-config
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4+git20141006+r54582+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1)
[0x9b92910] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x9c1bab0] skins2 interface error: no suitable dialogs provider found (hint: compile the qt4 plugin, and make sure it is loaded properly)
[0x9c1bab0] skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs provider
[0x9c1bab0] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try purging the configuration files and install again -

`sudo apt-get purge vlc*`

`sudo apt-get clean`

`sudo apt-get install vlc`

In case VLC starts working after `vlc --ignore-config`, the config files are broken.

To reset them - `vlc --reset-config`

Comment: I've seen that in other posts. tried, but did not work.

Comment: I have VLC 2.1.4 running on my 14.04 installation. Try installing that instead of the 2.1.6 you have.

Comment: i had 2.1.4 installed. that didn't work. then updated to 2.1.6. showing same things.

Comment: What is the output of `vlc -I skins2` and `vlc -I qt4`

Comment: Otherwise try `vlc --ignore-config`

Comment: a third party software was using previous version of QT, which in this case caused the issue. uninstalling that software solved this issue. thanks.